# In asp.net, Web Service endpoint is incorrect when client connects to production server

Tags: asp.net, service, ip-address, endpoint

I've been scouring the net for almost two days and must be missing something (possibly basic).

On the test (local) web server I have set up a simple service, and using a client, I discover the service and run it without problems.

Using the same client, I discover the same service, but on the production server using https://MyNewStuff.com/WebServices/MyService.asmx (the real internet address of the service) without problems, but when I try to run it it fails with an EndPointNotFound exception. Upon investigating I find that the client's app.config is incorrect as follows;

```
        <endpoint address="https://ProductionWeb.Ourdomain.com/WebServices/MyService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceSoap"
            contract="MOX24.MyServiceSoap" name="MyServiceSoap" />
```

i.e., not set up correctly as it reflects https://ProductionWeb.Ourdomain.com ...  and not https://MyNewStuff.com/WebServices, indicating that the service (discovery) is sending the wrong information to the clients (it is sending the server's name and domain and not the 'web' name).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If your client is a web application, put https://MyNewStuff.com/WebServices/MyService.asmx in the Web.Release.config.

Comment: That is exactly what seems to be the problem. How do I do that, from the server side?

Comment: Sorry Adrian, my previous answer was premature and misguided, so I edited now, to assume your client is a web application. Is it?

Comment: My client is a forms application, but it is just a test bench. We are developing web services that clients may communicate with using their own software (whether web, apps, phone, etc). They are discovering the service descriptions etc ok but when they try to run them, then get endpoint address errors as the endpoint specified on their end is not the proper 'web' address (but the internal one which is not reachable via the net). They then have to correct the endpoint address manually and move on. But this is not convenient and should be automatic.

Comment: So you're publishing a .config file with your Windows application? If it's just for testing, I would recommend setting the default endpoint to the production endpoint and then only overriding the setting in your local test environment

Comment: No of course not (how can you publish .config?) Sorry I must admit I cannot understand that part. And with regards to setting the endpoint, as I asked above, how?

Comment: You can set your default endpoint to the production endpoint. You do this by connecting to that when you set up the service reference from your local application. Then, when you develop locally, you can edit this endpoint in App.config of the local application. As the client doesn't get App.config, they will have no option but to use the production endpoint.